# add two types of casting into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I have column called salary in my table. Another table the values are stored like

- 5 lakhs 12 thousand likewise..

**I want the result**

- 5*10000+12*1000

**I created one query,**

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES('+
CAST(SUBSTRING(
      CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
      + ',' +CAST(SUBSTRING(
      CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4
    ,patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS VARCHAR(50))+')'
    FROM requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```

Here I can multiply separate values. I can't do add two values.

when i use above query my result is

```
INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES(200000,5000)
```

**Expected output:**

```
INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES(205000)
```

Comment: woudnt be better to have a new column with the decimal value instead only the text value?

Comment: My new db structure is like that. so i have to do this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES('+
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000
            + SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4, 
                                                       patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000 AS VARCHAR(50))+')'
    FROM requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```